# JPA unidirectional @OneToOne relationship with shared primary key always trigger a secondary query even if fetchType is EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am building a blog system, and like to provide the upvote/downvote feature for the blog. Since the vote count number of blog should be persisted, i choose to use MySQL to act as the data store. And i use Spring JPA(Hibernate) to do the ORM job. Here's my data objects:

```java
class Blog{
    // ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private BlogVoteCounter voteCounter;    
}
```

And the counter class:

```java
@Entity
public class BlogVoteCounter extends ManuallyAssignIdEntitySuperClass<Long> {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Integer value;
}
```

The reason why i separate the `BlogVoteCounter` from `Blog` is that i think the `voteCount` field will be modified by a totally different frequency comparing to other fields of Blog, since i want to use cache to cache the `Blog`, following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching), i choose to separate them.

However, since the `VoteCount` field might be always needed when return the Blog object to the front end, and to avoid the n+1 problem, i declared the `BlogVoteCounter` field in Blog class with EAGER fetch type.

I've already seen [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Thus according to my personal comprehension, i use  unidirectional relationship and only declare `OneToOne` in the `Blog` side.

However, when i examine the query, it turns out that jpa will still trigger a secondary query to retrieve `BlogVoteCounter` from database without simply using a join when use `findAll` method on `BlogRepository`.

```sql
    select
        blogvoteco0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        blogvoteco0_.value as value2_2_0_ 
    from
        blog_vote_counter blogvoteco0_ 
    where
        blogvoteco0_.id=?
```

So how should i config, to always make the `BlogVoteCounter` field in `Blog` be fetched eagerly.

---

The usage of `ManuallyAssignIdEntitySuperClass` is following the Spring JPA [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites), since i manually assign id for `BlogVoteCounter` class.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ManuallyAssignIdEntitySuperClass<ID> implements Persistable<ID> {

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew(){
        this.isNew = false;
    }
}
```

And the `BlogRepository` is derived from `JpaRepository`

```java
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long>{
    // ...
}
```

I trigger the query by using `findAll` method, but using `findById` or other conditional query seems no difference.

Comment: use a fetch join within the query to control what is joined and how. Eagerly fetched relationships are only required to be fetched by the JPA spec before the object is returned, and it doesn't state how.

Comment: Why are you using the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation? If you want it unidirectional - try specifying the join column, but mark it as insertable=false, updateable=false, as this PrimaryKeyJoinColumn might be why Hibernate isn't auto joining this eager relationship. Personally, I'd go with a bidirectional one so you don't have to bother with setting the BlogVoteCounter.id value yourself. Do what is right for your application and its needs, not what arbitrary 'this is best' articles may tell you, as they may not be correct for your end use cases.

Comment: @Chris But after seeing [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), it state that the unidirectional relationship will cause a extra query, which is what i try to avoid.

Comment: @user8510613 What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @Chris beside, i also try mark it as ```@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)```, it doesn't help.

Comment: @SternK I am using Spring Boot 2.2.1, the Hibernate version seems to be 5.4.8

Answer (score 1):

> `When to fetch` vs `How to fetch`  :   `fetchType`  defines when to fetch the association ( `instantly`vs `later when someone access`)  the association but not how to fetch the association(i.e second select vs join query).  So from JPA Spec point of view, EAGER means dont wait until someone access that field to populate it but JPA provider is free to use JOIN or second select as long as they do it immediately.

> Even though they are free to use join vs second select, still I thought they should have optimised for join in the case of EAGER. So interested in finding out the logical reasoning for not using the join

**1. Query generated for `repository.findById(blogId);`**

```
    select
        blog0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        blog0_.vote_counter_id as vote_cou2_0_0_,
        blogvoteco1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        blogvoteco1_.value as value2_1_1_ 
    from
        blog blog0_ 
    inner join
        blog_vote_counter blogvoteco1_ 
            on blog0_.vote_counter_id=blogvoteco1_.id 
    where
        blog0_.id=?
```

**2. Updated Mapping**

```
public class Blog {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private BlogVoteCounter voteCounter;

    public Blog() {
    }

    public Blog(Long id, BlogVoteCounter voteCounter) {
        this.id = id;
        this.voteCounter = voteCounter;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BlogVoteCounter getVoteCounter() {
        return voteCounter;
    }

    public void setVoteCounter(BlogVoteCounter voteCounter) {
        this.voteCounter = voteCounter;
    }
}
```

**3. Issues with current Mapping**

- As per your mapping, it is impossible to create `blog` and `votecounter` as it causes a `chicken and egg` problem.
  i.e
- blog and votecounter need to share the same primary key
- blog's primary key is generated by database.
- so in order to get the primary key of blog and assign it to votecounter as well, you need to store blog first
- but the @OneToOne relationship is not optional, so you cannot store blog first alone

**4.Changes**

- Either need to make the relationship optional so blog can be stored first, get the id, assign to BlogVoteCounter and save the counter
- Or Don't auto generate Id and manually assign the id so blog and votecounter can be saved at the same time.(I have gone for this option but you can do first option)

**5.Notes**

- default `repository.findAll` was generating 2 queries so I overridden that method to generate one join query

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long> {

    @Override
    @Query("SELECT b from Blog b join fetch b.voteCounter ")
    List<Blog> findAll();
}
```

```
    select
        blog0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        blogvoteco1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        blog0_.vote_counter_id as vote_cou2_0_0_,
        blogvoteco1_.value as value2_1_1_ 
    from
        blog blog0_ 
    inner join
        blog_vote_counter blogvoteco1_ 
            on blog0_.vote_counter_id=blogvoteco1_.id
```

Comment: about the chicken egg problem, our human knows that they share the primary key, thus can use one query to join them, and i think annotation like ```@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn``` or ```@MapsId``` is to tell the JPA/Hibernate about it, but it seems no help at all, did i misunderstand them?

Comment: ```Blog saved = blogRepository.save(blog); BlogVoteCounter blogVoteCounter = new BlogVoteCounter(saved.getId());
        saved.setVoteCounter(blogVoteCounterRepository.save(blogVoteCounter));```

Comment: Of course, a ```@Transactional``` here. I've tried to follow https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-same-primary-key-one-to-one-association/, but not working.